# Separated grails plugin for batch processing

Tags: jakarta-ee, grails, quartz-scheduler, spring-batch

I would like to ask a question about the logic of some plug-in using Grails and Spring batch, well is it possible to implement a batch processing module separated from the application (the application read data files and insert them into database) ? and what exactly to pass in parameters ? Actually I am looking forward to build a generic plug-in for Grails that allows these operations for such applications.

P.S : I am not talking about quartz that helps to schedule tasks.

Thanks.

Comment: are you looking to build a component to invoke batch jobs?  or define them?

Comment: Hi sir, the component has to make possible a batch processing without being attached to the logic of the application itself, and it has to do both of the operations you have indicated. I mean the application does not have to implement the operations in its service layer, all of that should be separated in another module. by the way Is that even possible ?
thanks

Comment: it would be possible to use the spring-batch-admin components to start a job from a grails app, along with pass through an xml definition for runtime updating of job configurations.  can you give a particular high level use case and i'll try and help a bit more